# how i can handle this type of data using groovy in soap ui "Destination has -"425637.10"- Source has -"425637.1"

Tags: soap, groovy

i have data like Destination has -"425637.10",Source has -"425637.1"

these are amount fields so it cant be rounded /trim. ineed exact values to be matched. .

i need to compare these two values on some condition like

if( source data/destination data contains" some criteria") then  it should compare these values .

please let me know if u need more details.

TIA

Comment: Are they numbers? They're the same number you see... Just different display formatting

Comment: yes the format is different . i have 123 .12 in my source and dest 123.120   but i should compare and them and print if they are same.

Comment: i should write some groovy script which applies to this type of data

Answer (score 0):

Convert them to BigDecimals, and compare as normal:

```
def source = '425637.10'
def destination = '425637.1'

assert (source as BigDecimal) == (destination as BigDecimal)
```

Comment: i tried something like this  ,  it didnt worked.  could you you suggest any other approach                                                         if(sourceData.isDouble() && destData.isDouble()){                                     assert (source as BigDecimal) == (destination as BigDecimal) }

Comment: In what way didn't it work? Probably because source data and dest data are not doubles, they are strings